# UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame Notification not called with emoji keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, keyboard, emoji

First I had a UIViewController listenning for the UIKeyboardWillShow notification to adjust the screen for the keyboard. But every time I changed to emoji keyboard, the notification wasn't called.

So, I changed to UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame notification like this

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.keyboardChanged(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
```

It seems to work fine if I just change to emoji by tapping keyboard type.

However, if I press and hold keyboard type to select (my keyboard have more than one language) and select the emoji keyboard, the notification is not fired.

Anyone had something like this before? Any suggestions?

Comment: My app adjusts the screen based on if the keyboard shows or not and it works fine for when emoji keyboard is selected as well. Do you mind showing your code?

Comment: I edit my question @TPN1994. But I really just add the observer and it works just fine for the other cases. I'm thinking this can be a problem on iOS 11 because on other devices it works fine too... :/

Comment: if you put breakpoints/print statements do you see that it's always the case that it's not called? I remember I had a weird bug where either `UIKeyboardWillShow` or `UIKeyboardWillHide` wasn't being called even though I was observing them. Unfortunately, I can't remember which one it was. Nonetheless, posting the entire code could help still.

Comment: I have this problem as well. **However, if I press and hold keyboard type to select (my keyboard have more than one language) and select the emoji keyboard, the notification is not fired.** < this is key to causing the problem. If you short-tap to change to emoji the notification is fired properly, but not when holding down the "globe" button for a while, selecting emoji.

Comment: Also this only seems to happen on iOS 11.

Comment: I think this is a bug in iOS 11, I reported it to radar with ID: 34540300

Comment: Good to know that, @Jonny. If you want to post it below, I can mark it as a answer.

Comment: I just wish there was some workaround at least. Maybe another way to check the keyboard frame, if so even with a timer... it could be limited to iOS 11 until Apple fixes this. The app I have puts some element right on top of the keyboard and that element needs to stay visible.

Comment: I have a similar problem.  When jumping between UITextFields, neither the UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame or UIKeyboardDidShow notification are fired anymore.  In iOS10 it was still firing.  My emoji keyboard does, however, fire the UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame notification, but I can see my emoji keyboard is visibly higher than my normal keyboard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug in iOS 11, but there is a **hacky temporary solution:**

You can listen language mode changes:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(inputModeDidChange(_:)), name: .UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChange, object: nil)
```

And check for emoji:

```
if([[UITextInputMode currentInputMode].primaryLanguage isEqualToString:@"emoji"]) // layout again
```