# Why does NotificationCenter not calling the selector for UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame (iOS 11)?

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, nsnotificationcenter, uikeyboard

I registered an observer for the `UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame` notification, but the selector is never invoked. Below were the scenarios.

When the keyboard was shown, I long pressed the emoji.

1. I selected the `Emoji` option, the selector is not called.
2. I selected the `Keyboard Settings...` option, toggled the `Predictive` option, and go back to the app, the selector is not called.

Is this a bug in iOS 11? It is working in iOS 10 though.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIKeyboardWillChangeFrame Notification not called with emoji keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46287136/uikeyboardwillchangeframe-notification-not-called-with-emoji-keyboard)

Comment: It's indeed a bug in iOS 11. I'd say don't bother fixing it, it's Apple's fault. It even happens in big apps (e.g. Messenger) and system apps.