# iOS: How to detect keyboard change event

Tags: ios, swift, uikeyboard

Xcode 9.2, iOS 10.0+ , swift4.

I'm working on a project where user inputs english characters in `UITextField` and it converted to Japanese language characters. and it is working perfect. now, i want to allow user to input Japanese language characters direct from Japanese Keyboard.In this situation i want to know that the keyboard is changed from default to another type/language.

So, is there any function or Notification is available that can help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChange` notification to detect when the current keyboard language changes.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(inputModeDidChange), name: .UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChange, object: nil)

@objc func inputModeDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let inputMode = notification.object as? UITextInputMode {
        if let lang = inputMode.primaryLanguage {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i implemented same but not getting notification. i tapped on globe icon and it shows multiple keyboard and when i changed it. it doesn't fire the notification. :(

Comment: i got this answer **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46287136/uikeyboardwillchangeframe-notification-not-called-with-emoji-keyboard** . i tested with iOS10 simulator and yes it fires notification but not in iOS 11.  but Any way, Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In newer Swift versions the notification has been renamed to `UITextInputMode.currentInputModeDidChangeNotification`

Answer (score 1):

Register to receive the following notification:

`UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification`

And anytime the keyboard language changes, you'll receive a notification. You can get more info from [UITextInputMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinputmode) docs.

Answer (score 1):

With recent changes to iOS 12, swift 5.0 you can try:

```
func prepareForKeyboardChangeNotification() {
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(changeInputMode), name: UITextInputMode.currentInputModeDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
}

@objc
func changeInputMode(notification: NSNotification) {
    let inputMethod = txtInput.textInputMode?.primaryLanguage
    //perform your logic here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in swift 4.2

```
 //keyboard type change
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(inputModeDidChange), name: UITextInputMode.currentInputModeDidChangeNotification, object: nil)


@objc func inputModeDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
    if let inputMode = notification.object as? UITextInputMode {
        if let lang = inputMode.primaryLanguage {
            print("langueage:: \(lang)")
        }
    }
}
```